Proof in formal theory.
Axiom: $A \leq A$
Rules:
$ \frac{A\leq C}{min(A,B)\leq C}$ $\frac{A\leq C; B\leq C}{max(A,B)\leq C}$
$\frac{min(A,B)\leq C}{min(B,A)\leq C}$ $\frac{A\leq max(B,C)}{A)\leq max(C,B)}$
$\frac{A\leq B; A\leq C}{A\leq min(B, C)}$ $\frac{A\leq B}{A\leq max(B,C)}$ $\frac{A\leq B; B\leq C}{A\leq C} $
Alphabet:  $\Sigma= ({  F, P, I, x, y, z, /, min, max, \leq })$
Grammar rules: $P \rightarrow x; y; z; P/$, $I\rightarrow P; min(I,I);max(I,I)$ and $F\rightarrow I\leq I$.
Prove $$\vdash x\leq min(x, max(x,y))$$
Okay, so I start from the Axiom:

$A\leq A$ Is this equivalent to $F$? Then I can apply one of those grammar rules and have

$I\leq I$

$P \leq min(I, I)$

$x \leq min(x, max(I, I))$

$x \leq min(x, max(x, y))$
And this is finished proof but I didn't use any of those rules for $A$ so I think this is completely wrong.
I have absolutely no intuition for this please help.



Don't start from the axioms; start from the conclusion and look for rules that might apply.

The grammar rules only define what sentences are syntactically valid, and don't say anything about whether those sentences are true. To show that a statement is true you have to use the inference rules.

@anankElpis Can you show me how to do it? I have no idea how to do it. The only rule I can see as being a potential start is the $\frac{A\leq B; A\leq C}{A\leq min(B, C)}$ and that is in the case of $A=B, A=C$. I'm genuinely confused now, please explain the whole process. (Especially the one where we go from the rules for $A$ to the rules of the grammar. Does $A \rightarrow I$ for example??)

Forget about the grammar. Yes, you have to apply that rule with $A = x$, $B = x$, $C = \mathrm{max}(x, y)$.
